# Set variable to NULL if not found in query statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following code

```
DECLARE @a INT

SET @a = 1

SELECT TOP 1
    @a = id
FROM
    test
WHERE
    name = 'notexist'

SELECT @a
```

variable `@a` will still have `1` value if the `SELECT` statement doesn't find any row, is it possible to set the `@a` variable to null if the `SELECT` statement doesn't find any row without adding `SET @a = NULL` before `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Initialize to the desired default, in this case null, right before the select statement. Or use a conditional on @@ROWCOUNT after as others have said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign value this way

```
SET @a = (
SELECT TOP 1
    id
FROM
    test
WHERE
    name = 'notexist'
)

SELECT @a
```

Comment: what if I need to assign multiple variable at once? means that I'm forced to use `SELECT` statement instead of `SET`. Is it possible?

Comment: SET works with one variable at a time. If you have to do more, you could check the @@rowcount and set all your variables to null if it's zero.

Comment: This will technically work, but is misleading to learners who might assume that this is both good practice and potentially the _only_ way to set a variable to null if a query returned no results.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1
    @a = id
FROM
    test
WHERE
    name = 'notexist'

If @@rowcount = 0
set @a = NULL
```

or

```
set @a = case when @@rowcount = 0 then null else @a end
```

But its better to avoid the initialization of `1`. By default it will be `NULL`

Comment: the init is just an example because in real case, I need to reuse a variable that already have a value.

Answer (score 0):

The general advice in this scenario is to `declare` or otherwise `set` the variable to the *null* state before your query, this is the default value that should be returned by your logic.

Then your query will assign value only if there are any matching rows.

In essence, all you should have done was initialize the `@a` to `null` (the default value) and now assigned 1 at all, in fact assigning 1 at all is confusing to those reading your code, the value provides no *value* in this context, especially if we do not want to see that `1` in the output.

```
DECLARE @a INT

SELECT TOP 1
    @a = id
FROM
    test
WHERE
    name = 'notexist'

SELECT @a
```

If you really wanted to declare the `null` value, you could do it like this:

```
DECLARE @a INT = null;
```

You would generally try to avoid the superfluous lookup at the end of your code to determine if a `null` should be returned at all as this is additional conditional logic that can adversely affect query optimisation.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @variable varchar(max), @null varchar(max)
set @variable = 'value'
select @variable
set @variable = @null
select isnull(@variable,'is null')
```

Since the variable @null is never assigned a value it is NULL

Comment: Why have you bothered to declare a variable to hold the literal value of `null`? In fact this SQL make no sense. OP asked 6 years ago, we hope they have moved beyond this, but your post needs extended documentation to explain why we should vote for it and why it is better than the other answers. I agree the other answers are of low quality, but that is no excuse for this non-answer. Prove me wrong by including some justification for your solution.